# Displaying a FireFox toolbar from within that toolbar's JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hide, xul, show, toolbar

I'm putting together a FireFox toolbar that is only relevent to a small number of websites.

Currently I have code working that checks whether the user is viewing one of those sites and enables and disables the toolbar controls based on that check - that is all good.

I want to extend this, however, so that if the toolbar is not currently being displayed and the user visits one of the relevent sites then the toolbar is automatically displayed.

I've tried inspecting and setting sthe toolbar.hidden property (as set in my XUL) but that seems t be permanently set to 'false' (as per the value in the .xul file) even when the toolbar has been hidden by deselecting it in the View->Toolbars menu.

The code I was using for this is as folows:

```
checkMyToolBarVisible: function()
{
    if ( document.getElementById("MyToolBar-Toolbar").hidden == true )
    {
        document.getElementById("MyToolBar-Toolbar").hidden = false;
    }
},
```

I added an if satement to this to report the current status of the hidden property/attribute but as I say that always reported back that hidden=false even when the toolbar was not displayed. The function was firing properly, though, so the problem wasn;t that my toolbar code is being ignore when the toolbar is not displayed.

Looking at the documentation toolbar.hidden may not even be a supported property so if this is possible then I guess I'm looking at the wrong property to check and set.

Is this possible? And if so what property should I be working with?

Thanks,

FM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And once again proving that asking a question on a forum means you will find the answer yourself sooner rather than later I found the answer to this is some sample code while looking at a completely different issue!

The parameter is: .collapsed, ie

```
checkMyToolBarVisible: function()
{
    if ( document.getElementById("MyToolBar-Toolbar").collapsed == true )
    {
        document.getElementById("MyToolBar-Toolbar").collapsed = false;
    }
},
```

So, all sorted then... hope someone finds that useful as I couldn't find any reference to that in that context anywhere.

-FM